# I want to filter array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I got two arrays from API call, 
One is nameArray - which contains recipe names ( `menuNameArray = ["pohe","bread","cheese chilli toast"]`
And another array - which contains prices of those recipes `(menuPriceArray = ["10", "40", "120"]`.

I have got theses two arrays from API call.

I am displaying both the arrays on the table view & I am searching through the menuNamesArray because I want to search by recipe names.

I am getting recipe names by searching those from menuNameArray. Now I want menuPriceArray to get updated also according to searched menuName Array. 
means if I search for "bread" then I must get price value as "40" and accordingly for other names also.

How should I perform such filtering on the second array?

**My code Snippet -**

```
//MARK: UISearch result update delegate

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    // here arrFilter is the resulting array to sotre searched items from menuNamesArray
    arrFilter.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (menuNamesArray as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)

    let result = menuPriceArray.firstIndex(of: array.startIndex)
    arrFilter = array as! [String]

    self.tblSearch.reloadData()

    //here now I got the searched menu names, Now I want prices for searched menu names from menuPrice Array..
}
```

Comment: Merge the two arrays into a single array of an appropriate struct that contains both the name and the price

Comment: You surely tried _something_. Please [edit] your answer with your actual code. Without showing at least some effort, you'll most likely not receive an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Never use multiple arrays as data source**.

Swift is an object oriented language. Take advantage of it.

Create a struct

```
struct Menu {
    let name : String
    let price : Double
}
```

and a data source array

```
var menues = [Menu]()
```

Filter the array by `name` and get the price, pretty easy and straightforward

```
if let foundMenu = menues.filter(where: {$0.name == "bread"}) {
    print(foundMenu.price)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two arrays into one array of dictionary elements.